# How to filter on developers in C3.ai COVID-19 Data Lake therapeutic assets

Tags: postman

I'm trying out the [COVID-19 Data Lake](https://c3.ai/covid/) with Postman. I am running `POST https://api.c3.ai/covid/api/1/therapeuticasset/fetch` to get vaccines produced by a specific organization. But it looks like developers can include multiple organizations, so I can't just filter on the name like `"developer == 'Vanderbilt'"`.

I also tried `"'Vanderbilt' in developer"`.  How do I find all of the therapies that involve a specific university?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what rsyoung has said - you could use the `intersects()` expression engine function to filter on multiple organizations.

```
Check if first argument (object or arry) is present within remaining arguments.
Example: intersects(arryField, ['a','b','c']):
```

So in your case, you could use a filter such as:

```
intersects(developer, ['Vanderbilt', 'OrganizationX', 'OrganizationY'])
```

and the result should include all TherapeuticAssets that satisfy that condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with "contains(developer, 'Vanderbilt')"!